# GLSL - Checking for set attributes

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I have a vertex shader with attributes that may or may not be set in any given frame. How can I check whether or not these attributes have been set?

What I'd like to do:

```
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec4 color;
attribute vec2 textureCoord;


uniform mat4 perspective;
uniform mat4 modelview;
uniform mat4 camera;
uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

varying lowp vec4 vColor;

void main() {
    gl_Position = perspective * camera * modelview * vec4(position, 1.0);
 if ((bool)textureCoord) { // syntax error
     vColor = texture2D(textureSampler, textureCoord);
 } else {
     vColor = (bool)color ? color : vec4((normal.xyz + 1.0)/2.0 , 1.0); 
 }
}
```

Comment: We're talking about GL ES 2, I pressume?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have a vertex shader with attributes that may or may not be set in any given frame.

No, you don't. :)

With attributes, it's impossible that an attribute wouldn't be "set". Every vertex shader instance receives valid values from every declared attribute.

If the attribute array is not enabled by `glEnableVertexArray`, then the default attribute (as specified by `glVertexAttrib` and its defaults) will be passed.

---

In your case, you can either:

- compile your shader in different versions with or without texturing (conditional compilation is your friend; google for UberShader),
- use an uniform variable like "useTexturing" to save on shader switches.

Pick one.

Comment: Oh btw, one exception to what I said- the attribute is likely to be optimised out by the compiler/linker (i.e. removed from shader code and answer with -1 in response to `getVertexAttribLocation`) if it's not used anywhere in the shader code. But that's not the case.

Comment: @Kos Good to know that openGL manages itself at this point. Do you know which default values will be used if nothing else is defined?

Comment: I'd expect 0 or undefined, but can't tell out of my head. Best to just set it once